# Move the overlapping application to bit down in x-axis from my application. MFC

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, position, docking

Is it possible to change the `position` of other applications which is `sharing the same area on screen` as mine application.

**I need the following output:**

[image]

In this picture you can see my toolbar is at the top and it has shifted the browser to bit down so that both menu is visible but my application should always be on top in Z co-ordinate.

**Right now what exactly my application looks like.**

[image]

It is overlapping the toolbar of browser.

Please Suggest what should i do?

Answer (score 1):

Use [SetWindowPos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with HWND_TOPMOST in this situation. But you need to remove the flag again, because it would keep your window over all other windows.

Or just use set SetWindowPos hWndInsertAfter parameter.

Comment: sir i have already put this in my code like this `SetWindowPos(&wndTopMost, 10, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE);` but it is not helping me to fulfill my requirement.

Comment: What happens? Did you read the documentation of SetWindowPos. There are a view requirements. Also you can directly manipulate the Z-Oder in defining exactly the window handle you want.

Comment: yes @xmMRi i have already use it for topmost of all application in Z axis and it is working fine but i also want my application to be the top most of all other application in  x -axis also.

Comment: can you please reply with example?

Comment: Sorry! I have no sample, that Looks other like the simple call of that function.

Comment: did you got my problem i have tried with `SetWindowPos(&wndTopMost, 10, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE)` and all other flags but no one can solve my problem. please help.

Comment: I used the ZOrder Change successfully in some cases were I needed a non modal Dialog always above my Windows...

Comment: but i need To top the dialogs in X axis such that all other dialog is not hidden by my application while they will shift liitle below from my client area.

Comment: Top most is top most. There is nothing more than top most! May be you didn't use the correct window handle. Must not be a child window. Must be a top Level window.

Comment: i am trying to do is when it is in maximized form it will act as a task pane.i.e. all other windows menu doesn't get hide but shift a bit below so that we can use them also.